# Display Label on a Line Chart in ireport

Tags: jasper-reports, linechart

I am new to ireport and I want to have a line Chart.
I want to know is there anyway to add a label on the chart axis?
I think that I should set the Value Axis Label Expression, but how can I set it to  a string like: "hours"?

Also, is there any way to show some numbers on the points in the line chart?

Comment: Your question is not clear.What chart are you using?

Answer (score 0):

First Pass the label Names into separate Array and pass that array to line ChartData........LineChartData *data = [[LineChartData alloc] initWithXVals:arrayName dataSets:dataSets];